# How can I join two React Native applications

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am having some trouble trying to join two react native applications.
Let me explain to you.

I have two applications.
The first one is the login application.
The second one is the application itself(this app is related to flashcards).

I tried to join the two, but it didn't work.
The folders structures seem different from each other, and I do not know how to solve this problem

[Flash Cards application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LpNgu.png)

[Login application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6js6.png)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you explain better what do you mean with joining two apps? If you try to include in your question what have you tried would help too

Answer (score 0):

Join the files and add the the component App.js from Flash Cards in home screen Login Project.
and fix imports and packages